# Correct TypeScript Type for thunk dispatch?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I have an asynchronous redux action and so am using the thunk middleware.

I have `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` and `connect` functions for a component as follows:

```
const mapStateToProps = (store: IApplicationState) => {
  return {
    loading: store.products.loading,
    products: store.products.products
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
  return {
    getAllProducts: () => dispatch(getAllProducts())
  };
};
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ProductsPage);
```

**This all works but I wondered if is possible to replace the `any` type on the dispatch parameter in `mapDispatchToProps`?**

I tried `ThunkDispatch<IApplicationState, void, Action>` but get the following TypeScript error on the connect function:

```
Argument of type 'typeof ProductsPage' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Matching<{ loading: boolean; products: IProduct[]; } & { getAllProducts: () => Promise<void>; }, IProps>>'.
  Type 'typeof ProductsPage' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<Matching<{ loading: boolean; products: IProduct[]; } & { getAllProducts: () => Promise<void>; }, IProps>, any>'.
    Types of property 'getDerivedStateFromProps' are incompatible.
      Type '(props: IProps, state: IState) => { products: IProduct[]; search: string; }' is not assignable to type 'GetDerivedStateFromProps<Matching<{ loading: boolean; products: IProduct[]; } & { getAllProducts: () => Promise<void>; }, IProps>, any>'.
        Types of parameters 'props' and 'nextProps' are incompatible.
          Type 'Readonly<Matching<{ loading: boolean; products: IProduct[]; } & { getAllProducts: () => Promise<void>; }, IProps>>' is not assignable to type 'IProps'.
            Types of property 'getAllProducts' are incompatible.
              Type '() => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '() => (dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>) => Promise<void>'.
                Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>) => Promise<void>'.
                  Type 'Promise<void>' provides no match for the signature '(dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>): Promise<void>'.
```

[image]

**Is it possible to replace the `any` type on the dispatch parameter in `mapDispatchToProps`?**

Comment: What is the type signature of your `getAllProducts` thunk? I have an example of getting redux and redux-thunks typed with typesafe-actions [here](https://github.com/Yakimych/lift-log-react-ts/blob/master/src/components/App.tsx#L88), but it might be tricky to see the big picture. It could help to see the rest of your relevant code.

Answer (score 8):

This setup works very well for me:

```
// store.ts
//...
export type TAppState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export type TDispatch = ThunkDispatch<TAppState, void, AnyAction>;
export type TStore = Store<TAppState, AnyAction> & { dispatch: TDispatch };
export type TGetState = () => TAppState;
//...
const store: TStore = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers)
);
export default store;
```

Where `rootReducer` on my setup looks like this `const rootReducer = createRootReducer(history);`

```
// createRootReducer.ts
import { combineReducers, Reducer, AnyAction } from 'redux';
import { History } from 'history';
import {
  connectRouter,
  RouterState,
  LocationChangeAction,
} from 'connected-react-router';
// ... here imports of reducers
type TAction = AnyAction & LocationChangeAction<any>;

export type TRootReducer = Reducer<
  {
    // ... here types of the reducer data slices
    router: RouterState;
  },
  TAction
>;
const createRootReducer = (history: History): TRootReducer =>
  combineReducers({
    // ... here actual inserting imported reducers
    router: connectRouter(history),
  });

export default createRootReducer;
```

Then in connected component

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Add, { IProps } from './Add'; // Component
import { TDispatch, TAppState } from '../../store';

type TStateProps = Pick<
  IProps,
  'title' | 'data' | 'loading'
>;
const mapStateToProps = (
  state: TAppState,
): TStateProps => {
    // ... here you have typed state :)
    // and return the TStateProps object as required
    return {
      loading: state.someReducer.loading,
      //...
    }
}

type TDispatchProps = Pick<IProps,  'onSave'>;
const mapDispatchToProps = (
  dispatch: TDispatch,
): TDispatchProps => {
   // here you  have typed dispatch now
   // return the TDispatchProps object as required
   return {
    onSave: (): void => {
      dispatch(saveEntry()).then(() => {
        backButton();
      });
    },
   }
}
```

As for the thunk actions I do as follows

```
// this is a return type of the thunk
type TPromise = Promise<ISaveTaskResponse | Error>;

export const saveEntry = (): ThunkAction<
  TPromise, // thunk return type
  TAppState, // state type
  any, // extra argument, (not used)
  ISaveEntryAction // action type
> => (dispatch: TDispatch, getState: TGetState): TPromise => {
  // use getState
  // dispatch start saveEntry action
  // make async call
  return Axios.post('/some/endpoint', {}, {})
    .then((results: { data: ISaveTaskResponse; }): Promise<ISaveTaskResponse> => {
      // get results
      // you can dispatch finish saveEntry action
      return Promise.resolve(data);
    })
    .catch((error: Error): Promise<Error> => {
      // you can dispatch an error saveEntry action
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Redux can dispatch actions that are plain objects. Say we have such action `{type: 'ACTION2'}`. We can create action creator and wrap it inside dispatch like this

```
// This is our action
interface Action2 extends Action { type: "ACTION2"; }

// And this is action crator
const action2 = (): Action2 => ({ type: "ACTION2" });
```

With `thunk` middleware Redux can dispatch functions. And we can create async action like this

```
// This action will be dispatched from async action creator
interface Action1 extends Action { type: "ACTION1"; payload: string; }

// And async action creator
const thunkAction = (arg: string): ThunkAction<Promise<void>, {}, AppState, KnownActions> => 
    async dispatch => {
        const res = await asyncFunction(arg);
        dispatch({ type: "ACTION1", payload: res });
    },
```

Here `ThunkAction<R, S, E, A extends Action>` type is used. It accepts following type arguments:

- `R` stays for return type of the internal function. In the above example, internal function is async function so it returns `Promise<void>`
- `S` stays for the app state
- `E` is the extension attribute type which is not used
- `A` is type of the action. `KnownActions` in example above is the union of all possible action types (`type KnownActions = Action1 | Action2;`)

Now lets look at how component can be typed.

```
interface Component1DispatchProps {
  action2: () => Action2;
  thunkAction: (arg: string) => Promise<void>;
}

interface Component1StateProps {
  stateprop: string;
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (
  dispatch: ThunkDispatch<AppState, {}, KnownActions>
) => {
  return {
    action2: () => dispatch(action2()),
    thunkAction: (arg: string) => 
      dispatch(thunkAction(arg))
  };
};
```

`thunkAction` method returns `dispatch(thunkAction(arg))`, where `thunkAction(arg)` returns `ThunkAction<Promise<void>, {}, AppState, KnownActions>`. So `dispatch` will be called with the argument of type `ThunkAction` and will be resolved to

```
<TReturnType>(
  thunkAction: ThunkAction<TReturnType, TState, TExtraThunkArg, TBasicAction>,
): TReturnType;
```

As a result `dispatch(thunkAction(arg))` will return `TReturnType` or `Promise<void>` in our example. Such signature is set for `thunkAction` in `Component1DispatchProps`.

Complete example is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/thunkdispatch-fmpq4)

Answer (score 1):

You could also provide another override for the redux Dispatch function in your global type definition:

(put this inside global.d.ts or some other global type definition)

```
import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk';
import { Action } from 'redux';

declare module 'redux' {
    export interface Dispatch<A extends Action = AnyAction> {
        <T extends ThunkAction<any, any, any, any>>(action: T): T extends ThunkAction<infer K, any, any, any> ? K : never;
    }
}
```

And then in your mapDispatchToProps use Dispatch type and not ThunkDispatch.

Comment: This works really well thank you!

It makes a lot of sense, you would expect the middleware to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the problem is not with the type of the dispatch parameter but actually the **props type on the component**.

*Note: My solution is not using the function notation of `mapDispatchToProps` since that is [not recommended](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch) until necessary (and I did not needed it yet). But I guess this solution could be adapted to it (having the right sandbox).*

To define the props properly (without needing to create a copy-pasta interface) it is necessary to **separate the `mapDispatchToProps` into two pieces, one for reducer actions and one for thunk actions**.

To show this solution I've forked an example from another answer (thanks @Fyodor).

Full code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/thunkdispatch-forked-uss1b?file=/src/Component.tsx

Component props are a combination of:

```
interface ComponentOwnProps {
  ownprop: string;
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({
  stateprop: state.stateprop
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  action2
};

const mapDispatchThunkToProps = {
  thunkAction
};
```

The complete type of the props is defined as:

```
type ComponentProps = ComponentOwnProps &
  ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> &
  typeof mapDispatchToProps &
  ThunkProps<typeof mapDispatchThunkToProps>;
```

The only trick here is `ThunkProps` which converts the Thunk action types in the dictionary from "double function" `(args) => (dispatch, getState) => void` to the connected (and simpler) `(args) => void` functions.

```
// types from redux examples (usually in `store.ts`)
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  any, // or some ThunkExtraArgument interface
  Action<string>
>;

// the tricky part: convert each `(args) => AppThunk => void` to `(args) => void`
export type ThunkProps<T extends { [K in keyof T]: (...a: any[]) => AppThunk<void> }> = {
  [K in keyof T]: (...args: Parameters<T[K]>) => void;
};
```

... and finally you can connect the component

```
// don't forget to combine the two mapDispatch-es
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {...mapDispatchToProps, ...mapDispatchThunkToProps}
)(Component);
```

Full code (forked and updated from @Fyodor's answer): https://codesandbox.io/s/thunkdispatch-forked-uss1b?file=/src/Component.tsx ... all important code and types are in `Component.tsx` for convenience.

*Note: even though this solution has some limitations, for me it serves the purpose of **not writing unnecessary interfaces** and having **well typed props** including function params.*