# Typescript apparently deduces the wrong type for a dispatched Thunk

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

**Complete working codesandbox example** [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-typescript-forked-9yko4?file=/src/index.tsx)

I declare a simple action type and an asynchronous thunk that dispatches it:

```
type ActionType = { type: "foo"; v: number };

const FooThunk: ThunkAction<Promise<ActionType>, any, any, ActionType> = (dispatch): Promise<ActionType>
=> {
  return new Promise<number>((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(42);
    }, 100);
  }).then((v: number) => {
    return dispatch({ type: "foo", v });
  });
};
```

The question is now what is the type of the value I get when I call `dispatch(FooThunk)`.
Typescript thinks the type is `ThunkAction<Promise<ActionType>, any, any, ActionType>` and complains (on line 38 of the sandbox) with the following message:

```
'ThunkAction<Promise<ActionType>, any, any, ActionType>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<ActionType>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag]ts(2739)
```

However, when I log the value I get at runtime (line 48 of the codesandbox) I see clearly that it is a `Promise`. Searching on StackOverflow I have found contradictory answers.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64529787/274677) says that dispatching a thunk returns the thunk itself. Whereas [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59729326/274677) suggests that dispatching a thunk returns a Promise.

Typescript's type system seems to say that the type of dispatching a thunk is the same as the thunk itself. However at runtime I get a Promise object. What am I missing?

For completeness purposes only, I append the code that you will find the the sandbox (link provided above):

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { initialState, rootReducer } from "./rootReducer";
import "./styles.css";

import { ThunkDispatch as Dispatch, ThunkAction } from "redux-thunk";
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from "react-redux";

import { applyMiddleware } from "redux";

import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer /* preloadedState, */,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

//const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);

type ActionType = { type: "foo"; v: number };

const FooThunk: ThunkAction<Promise<ActionType>, any, any, ActionType> = (
  dispatch
): Promise<ActionType> => {
  return new Promise<number>((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(42);
    }, 100);
  }).then((v: number) => {
    return dispatch({ type: "foo", v });
  });
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<any, any, any>) => {
  return {
    dispatchFooThunk: (): Promise<ActionType> => dispatch(FooThunk)
  };
};
const connector = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps);

type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

class FooComponent_ extends React.Component<PropsFromRedux> {
  componentDidMount() {
    const p = this.props.dispatchFooThunk();
    console.log(p); // if you examine log output you see clearly that this is a PROMISE !
  }
  render() {
    return <div>foo</div>;
  }
}

const FooComponent = connector(FooComponent_);

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <FooComponent />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of a thunk is the return value of the thunk action itself. As a consequence: If it's an async function, it returns a Promise.

The normal `Dispatch` type does not know how to handle thunks though.
If you are using redux toolkit [this documentation part](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-dispatch-type) describes how to properly type your `useDispatch` hook with a Dispatch type inferred from the store configuration.
If you are using plain redux, you just can use the `ThunkDispatch` type. [This part of the react-redux documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#typing-the-usedispatch-hook) describes how to type your `useDispatch` hook in that case.

PS: in your specific case, your `ThunkDispatch<any, any, any>` is too generic. That last `any` will match too eagerly. Try a `ThunkDispatch<any, any, AnyAction>` instead, that will work.

Comment: PS: added a fix for your problem there. Also, if you're just learning redux with typescript right now, check out the [official redux toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/), as that will cut your boilerplate (and especially TypeScript types) down a lot and prevent a lot common errors.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that on my own and was coming back here to comment. I don't get it but it works. However, the links you supply say nothing about `ThunkDispatch` or how to type it. My codesandbox was already using `ConnectedProps` etc but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: Yeah, i didn't notice it at first because I had missed the CodeSandbox, sorry ^^
As for the "why" on the `any`: Take a look at the [type signature](https://unpkg.com/browse/redux-thunk@2.3.0/index.d.ts):
If the `A` parameter also matches a thunk (which `any` does), it will take the first overload, otherwise the second.